# How can I set Changed flag in ArcMap using ArcObjects.NET?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, editing

In my task I changes representation geometry in selected features.
When I edits something in ArcMap manually, question dialog about saving changes causes:

1. `Editor` - `Start editing`
2. Edit geometry
3. `Editor` - `Stop editing`
4. Question `Do you want to save your edits?`

But when I edits programmatically using ArcObjects.NET, editing stopping doesn't causes question, and all changes losts if they didn't save before stopping.

Where and what flag must I set for question about saving will be caused?

My code for editing:

```cs
for (int j = 0; j < map.LayerCount; j++)
{
    IFeatureLayer mapLayer = (IFeatureLayer)map.Layer[j];
    IGeoFeatureLayer geoLayer = (IGeoFeatureLayer)mapLayer;
    IFeatureClass mapFeatureClass = mapLayer.FeatureClass;
    ICursor mapCursor = (ICursor)mapFeatureClass.Search(filter, false);
    IFeature mapFeature = (mapCursor as IFeatureCursor).NextFeature();
    if (mapFeature != null && geoLayer.Renderer is IRepresentationRenderer)
    {
        IRepresentationClass repClass = (geoLayer.Renderer as IRepresentationRenderer).RepresentationClass;
        IRepresentation rep = repClass.GetRepresentation(mapFeature, mapContext);
        if (rep.Shape.GeometryType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
        {
            IPolygon polygon = (IPolygon)rep.ShapeEdit;
            rep.Shape = feature.Shape; // Geometry for representations just copies from another features
            rep.UpdateFeature();
            rep.Feature.Store();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed flag that I wanted sets by `IEditor.StartOperation` and `IEditor.StopOperation` methods:

```cs
UID eUID = new UIDClass();
eUID.Value = "esriEditor.Editor";
IEditor editor = (IEditor)ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(eUID);
editor.StartOperation();
/**
edits
**/
editor.StopOperation("My edits");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to start an edit-session before you can open an edit-operation (which is only a deeper closure). In ArcMap an edit-session automatically creates an edit-operation which can then be redone/undone. When doing this programmatically you have to manually open that operation.

So call this before starting your operation: `editor.StartEditing(myWorkspace)`.

After stopping the operation you then have to stop the session as well where you have to provide a boolean indicating if the changes should be saved to the database or not.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but my add-in assumes that edit mode is already enabled

Comment: Then you´ll get the questipn when stopping editing via the editor.